# Tricky SQL Join, is that even possible?

Tags: mysql

I try to solve a MySQL query issue thats bothering me for a while. I can only solve that using a script, not a single query and thats somewhat annoying.

I have the following Tables:

Voucher:
    VoucherID, VoucherDate, Name, Address ...

Voucher_Item:
    VoucherItemID, VoucherID, ArticleNr, Amount, Price ...

As the tables might tell you this is an online shop and we have here orders and order-articles per order linked via VoucherID as FK. So I can use

```
SELECT ...
FROM Voucher v
LEFT JOIN Voucher_Item vi USING(VoucherID)
WHERE ...
```

So far so good. Now I have the bad construction (I did not made this but I have to use it) that postage for the order is treated as one article.

It has a specific, unique per order - ArticleNr 'ponat1'.

So each order has atleast one or more rows of articles and among them can "ArticleNr = 'ponat1', and price in this case would contain the postage

Which means an order having postage would look like this:

```
Table Voucher:
VoucherID | VoucherDate | Name       | Address ...
1         |  2017-01-11 | Mr. Harper | Sunset Boulevard 1100 ...

Table Voucher_Items:
VoucherItemID | VoucherID | ArticleNr | Amount | Price ...
1             |  1        | ponat1    | 1      | 5.00 //(Postage)
2             |  1        | 08343433  | 2      | 3.95 //(Any other article)
```

Order without postage:

```
Table Voucher:
VoucherID | VoucherDate | Name       | Address ...
2         |  2017-01-08 | Mr. Marc   | Central Street 33 ...

Table Voucher_Items: //Note the misssing ArticleNr = 'ponat1' article as this order is postage free:

VoucherItemID | VoucherID | ArticleNr | Amount | Price ...
3             | 2         | 00548878  | 3      | 3.95 //(Any other article)
```

My question is now simple: how can I forge a query to receive all orders including postage using

```
WHERE ARticleNr = 'ponat1' OR ArticlenNr IS NULL
```

the big problem here is that ArticleNr is never actually NULL (because other articles always exist) but a row with ArticleNr = 'ponat1' simply never exists if the order is postage free which would mean orders without postage are missing in my result. Which I do not want.

I want them to be in the result array with 0€ postage instead.

Currently I always have to write a PHP script or so fetching all the orders and then fetching all the order_items and compare which order does not have an article with nr 'ponat1' to set its postage to 0 which is very annoying.

I tried LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, UNION LEFT AND RIGHT OUTER JOIN combinations and came up with no usable result.
Is this even solvable or is the table-structure just bad for this problem? Because I personally think that Voucher - postage is rather 1:1 relation and should be located in table Voucher with a single field instead but as I said I didnt create this unfortunate construct which we cannot change as we cannot change the system thats using that table structure.

Would be a great help to solve this using a single query.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you are looking for is slightly unclear, as you don't provide any example of the expected output. However, modifying your sample query, you can try the following:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Voucher v
LEFT JOIN Voucher_Item vi USING(VoucherID)
AND postage.ArticleNr <> 'ponat1'
LEFT OUTER JOIN Voucher_Item postage
ON postage.VoucherID = v.VoucherID
AND postage.ArticleNr = 'ponat1'
WHERE ...
```

Using the above structure, you can separate out postage items from other items. Just SELECT from the postage aliased table, checking if it is null or has a price.

Note that this will return one row for each record in the Voucher_Item table, and the Voucher_Item data will be null if there are no non-postage items. If you want just one row per Voucher record, you'll need to include more information on exactly what information you need. Likely GROUP BY will be needed at that point.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add an item (in your case postage), that is added to all vouchers;

```
INSERT INTO Voucher_Item VALUES (4, 0, 'ponat1', 0, 0.00);
```

Notice that `VoucherID` is `0` for this item.

Doing

```
SELECT v.VoucherID, vi.*
  FROM Voucher v LEFT JOIN Voucher_Item vi
    ON v.VoucherID = vi.VoucherID OR vi.VoucherID = 0
  ORDER BY v.VoucherID;
```

Will result in

```
VoucherID   VoucherItemID   VoucherID   ArticleNr   Amount  Price
1           2               1           08343433    2       3.95
1           4               0           ponat1      0       0
1           1               1           ponat1      1       5
2           3               2           00548878    3       3.95
2           4               0           ponat1      0       0
```

So we're almost there, only the vouchers with postage, now have postage twice. Luckily, since the postage amount and price of the default postage is 0, we can simply group by article number and do a sum on amount and price.

```
SELECT vi.VoucherItemId, v.VoucherID, vi.ArticleNr,
    SUM(vi.Amount) AS Amount, SUM(vi.Price) AS Price
  FROM Voucher v LEFT JOIN Voucher_Item vi
    ON v.VoucherID = vi.VoucherID OR vi.VoucherID = 0
  GROUP BY v.VoucherID, vi.ArticleNr
  ORDER BY v.VoucherID, vi.VoucherItemID;
```

Which result in

```
VoucherItemID   VoucherID   ArticleNr   Amount  Price
1               1           ponat1      1       5
2               1           08343433    2       3.95
3               2           00548878    3       3.95
4               2           ponat1      0       0
```

#### [See the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af90e/15)

---

**Edit to clarify that existing software isn't affected and existing data doesn't need to be changed:**

To implement this solution you only need insert 1 record into `Voucher_Item`, which will apply to all vouchers (created in the past and future).

Also if it will not affect the current software, as running the existing query will return the records without the addition postage record

```
SELECT vi.*
  FROM Voucher v INNER JOIN Voucher_Item vi
    ON v.VoucherID = vi.VoucherID
  ORDER BY v.VoucherID, vi.VoucherItemID;
```

Will still return

```
VoucherItemID   VoucherID   ArticleNr   Amount  Price
1               1           ponat1      1       5
2               1           08343433    2       3.95
3               2           00548878    3       3.95
```

Comment: Basically the idea is not that bad but requires alot of work on different places. (Webshop, fix current data, several scripts). Also the software will list postage article twice in this case. Otherwise I think duplicate articles per voucher ID are not possible because this is a unique-key for columns VoucherID and ArticleID as this would make no sense. I have to discuss this and think about it. It might be one helpful possiblity but its not directly solving the issue. Its rather hacking arround to solve databse-structure.

Comment: @Steini Please read the answer more closely. You only need to add one record to `Voucher_Item`. Since it has `VoucherId` 0, it should not show up in the software. Also you don't need to change the current data. I'll update the answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to add an additional (virtual) row when you don't have a postage row. You can do exactly that with a `union`:

```
SELECT ...
FROM 
  (select v.*, 
     vi.VoucherItemID, vi.ArticelNr, vi.Amount, vi.Price
   FROM Voucher v
   LEFT JOIN Voucher_Item vi -- maybe not a left join?
   on v.VoucherId = vi.VoucherID

   UNION   -- use "union all" if v.* is not unique

   SELECT v.*, 
     null as VoucherItemID, 'ponat1' as ArticleNr, 1 as Amount, 0 as Price
   FROM Voucher v
   WHERE not exists 
    (select 1 from Voucher_Item vi
     where v.VoucherID = vi.VoucherID 
     and vi.ArticleNr = 'ponat1')
  ) as v_compl
WHERE ...
```

It will take all the orders, and adds a row for each voucher it cannot find a `'ponat1'`-row for. An index on `(VoucherID, ArticleNr)` will help. You might want to create a view for that subquery, or use it as it is.

It will not recalculate the `VoucherItemID` (which is probably an autoincrement field). If you need that too, you can add another layer and calculate the row number and e.g. use the negative row number as the `VoucherItemID` or add a high enough offset to make it unique.

I'm not exactly sure why you use a `left join` when "each order has atleast one or more rows of articles", but for completeness, be aware that this query will also add a row to vouchers that have no items at all.